# Missing MP3 disc burner on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: mp3, burning

Every thread I went to told me, to burn MP3 disc I have to select data disc in Brasero or in other burning app. This is not true, I have wasted my CD ten times just to burning a working MP3 disc. It plays with some of my player but not all. To burn an MP3 disc with data mode on Brasero or other app is absolutely dumb.

On Windows, it has Ashampoo Burning Studio Free. It lets you burn MP3 disc that can be play on all player in one mode, and another mode that's PC/data mode which just copy MP3 files to disc. I have tested both mode, the same player which can't play the disc burnt in PC/data mode can play the same MP3 files burnt in MP3 disc mode. It's also described in the app that MP3 disc burnt in PC/data mode can only be play on PC.

If there's an app that can burn an actually MP3 disc, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: I've never heard anything about "MP3 disc mode". There are AudioCDs which hold about 70 minutes of music and can be played on any player, and there are "data CDs" which can contain any files including MP3s, and those can be played only on some players. Due to MP3 files being compressed, you usually can fit many hours of music on a data CD.

Comment: Some player can't play mp3 if they are inside in a folder and some player can. Possibly that's the problem.

Comment: @Sergey MP3 disc is MP3 CD/DVD/Blu-ray disc. And there are difference between data disc and MP3 disc. I used to think it's the same but not after it isn't working with my player. I think that's why it's put into difference mode in proper burning apps.

Comment: @Web-E My MP3 files were outside the folder. In fact, there were only MP3 files on my disc.

Comment: make sure your not burning 'on the fly' there is a current bug with that.

Comment: @Matt Barnes where can I turn off burning 'on the fly' in Brasero.

Comment: @KreaninwD.Unlimited Wikipedia says that MP3 CDs are normal data disks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3_CD: "Discs are written in the Yellow Book **standard data format** (used for **CD-ROMs**)"

As such, I suspect you problems may be related to - file name conventions (spaces in filenames, non-latin characters); - encoding of your MP3 files (using variable bitrate, some non-standard constant bitrate); - number of files on disk; - placing files in sub-directories

Comment: @KreaninwD.Unlimited its one of the options when you go to start burning the disk.  The top one. (I think) [link](http://mediaintro.teeks99.com/Audio/AudioScreen/Brasero-Burn.png)Here.  and I'm sorry its the 'Burn the image directly without saving it to disc' option.  Make sure its disabled.  (I coastered a number of cd's the other day before I figured this out)

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this a long time ago, but anyway, in case somebody else is experiencing this problem, which I did, I found a solution: Installing Nero Linux 4.
It burns MP3 CDs (in data mode), but they can be played on any mp3 capable player.